# python without comma after variables lead to TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python

```
people = [[7,0], [4,4], [7,1], [5,0], [6,1], [5,2]]
p = people[0]
a = []
a+=p[0]

TypeError       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-244e88383d16> in <module>()
      2 a = []
      3 type(p[0])
----> 4 a+=p[0]
      5 print(a)

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

When I add comma after `a+=p[0]` to change it into `a+=p[0],`. It works. Why? What does this comma do in this line of code?

Comment: You can think of `+=` on a list as syntactic sugar for `list.extend()` which takes an iterable as its argument.  Putting a comma after `p[0]` turns the integer at `p[0]` into a single item tuple containing the integer. Since tuples are iterable `+=` now works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comma creates a tuple.

```
1 # int
1, # a tuple, equivalent of (1,)
```

Since you can only add an iterable to a list, you can add a tuple but can't add an integer.

Comment: `type(7,) == int` using python 2.7

Comment: Oh, I understand, thank you!

Comment: @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ, Yeah, in this case the comma separates functions' arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Because `p[0]` is equal to 7 and hence can't be concatenated with another list. I don't know what you want to accomplish here, the only change I could suggest is

```
a += [p[0]] # or a.append(p[0]) if you don't mind mutating the original object
```

As far as adding a comma to the same is concerned, it works because implicitly it creates a tuple as @ForceBru suggested.

Comment: This wording is a bit Misleading. `append()` would work fine.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Changed it. Thanks.

Comment: how ever you didn't answer why `a += p[0],` works.

Comment: @ARMAN didn't see that statement in the question the first time.

Answer (score 0):

`a` is a `list` and the `+=` operator expects an `iterable` to append to the `list`:

```
>>> a = []
>>> a += [1, 2, 3]
>>> a += 1, 2, 3
>>> a += 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

The reason why this works is that adding a `,` to a number makes a `tuple` out of it, see:

```
>>> b = 1,
>>> type(b)
<class 'tuple'>
```